# Stop re-trying bounced emails in SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, massmail

I am developing a bulk email procedure, in that I have no issues in sending emails in batches. My problem starts when the recipients address is invalid or rejected by the host server.

Simply how can I tell the SMTP server not to retry it the original email was bounced.

I can only use MS Exchange Server.

Comment: I think its impossible to send a SMTP command to stop re-sending a message. As mentioned by @mit2935 it can be configured at SMTP Server level.

Answer (score 0):

The number of retries is a setting that you can configure in MS Exchange.  See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891103(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thanks but I need a solution which should be through SMTP commands. I don't want the re-trying to stop for all messages,but for certain messages

Comment: I don't think it's possible to manage the queue using SMTP commands, but it may be possible to do so using Powershell.  see http://blogs.technet.com/b/messaging_with_communications/archive/2011/04/22/how-to-manage-exchange-2010-message-queues.aspx